# Sitefinity get classification and all pages related

Tags: widget, sitefinity, custom-taxonomy

We are testing Telerik Sitefinity CMS to maybe use in a client and I have tried to create a custom widget to get a classification that I created and show all contents title as link.

Ex.:

- Countries

  - United Kingdom

    - London
    - Oxford
  - Brazil

    - Brasilia
    - Sao Paulo

Does anybody know how I can do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Until version 5.4 there is no way to have Sitefinity Pages hooked up to Taxonomies, if that is your question? (assuming it is, based on your title). This will probably be the case for Sitefinity 6.

You can get content items to be tagged and categorized with taxonomies and show them on a page. So e.g. News, Blogs, Dynamic Modules etc. This can be done by configuring one of the Taxonomy widgets to filter one of the Content types. This is all described in the Sitefinity Documentation.

Is that what you need?

Daniel